# Terminology for separability in price and value

Tags: microeconomics, utility, behavioral-economics, definition, risk-aversion

Take an agent with mean-variance utility over something that is uncertain:
$$
U(x) = \mu_x^\theta - \sigma_x^\lambda
$$

$A\in \{0,1\}$ happens if $U(x)>0$, and $x$ is a random variable

$$
A = \mathbf{1}\left(\mu_x^\theta - \sigma_x^\lambda >0\right)
$$

Saha (1997) has shown that $\theta$ different from 1 corresponds to DARA or IARA preferences.  If an agent isn't necessarily CARA, and $\mu = value - cost$, then the first term is 
$$
\mu_x^\theta = \left(E[value] - cost\right)^\theta
$$
This assumes that cost isn't separable from value.  In reality however, agents may not operate this way.  The simplest example is a cash/credit constraint.  You'd thus have 
$$
A = \mathbf{1}\left(\left(E[value] - cost\right)^\theta - \sigma_x^\lambda >0\right) s.t. cost < c
$$

Alternatively, maybe cash expenditures are psychically painful.  Like, even if I value something at \$5, the thought of not having that \$5 just *bothers* me.  Maybe because of loss of option value, for example.

$$
A = \mathbf{1}\left(\left(E[value] - cost\right)^\theta - \sigma_x^\lambda  - f(cost) >0\right) s.t. cost < c
$$
where $f$ is weakly positive and monotonic.

My questions:

1. Is there a specific term for this sort of separability in cost and value?
2. Would it go away entirely if there were no credit constraint?
3. And if I simply model $\left(value - cost\right)^\theta$ with a nonparametric $g(cost, value)$, would economists know what I am talking about if I justify it as represeting "non-classical behavior" or "deviations from the classical behavioral model?"